# Getting empty string values when splitting alphanumeric values using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list with string values like this:

```
AB65
```

I want to split the the letters from the numbers, but when I do this:

```
re.split('([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)', 'AB65')
```

I get the following with empty string values:

```
['', 'AB', '65', '']
```

How do I get the values like this: ['AB', '65']
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why a `.split` instead of a `.findall` for this example?

Comment: @JonClements I'm actually using the pandas str.split() function.

Comment: That's worth mentioning... because there's also `str.findall` as well in pandas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.split` is meant to get the text *between* regex matches; what you need is `re.findall` instead:

```
>>> re.findall('([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)', 'AB65') 
[('AB', '65')]
```

This still doesn't quite work, because the regex matches the entire string `'AB65'` and contains two capturing groups. So we need a regex that matches *either* letters *or* numbers (so separate them with a `|`), and uses non-capturing groups (so use `(?:…)`):

```
>>> re.findall('(?:[A-Z]+)|(?:[0-9]+)', 'AB65') 
['AB', '65']
```

In fact, in this simple case, the parentheses aren't even necessary:

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Z]+|[0-9]+', 'AB65') 
['AB', '65']
```